# How do you input an integer and have it sorted from highest to lowest

Tags: c++

How do you input an integer and have it sorted from highest to lowest  (ex. I input 123456 and it outputs 654321, the input can be custom). I have an issue with large numbers.

Comment: So you want to sort the digits in a string? Have you tried using [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: C is not C++ and C++ is not C etc... Have you tried anything? Please provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the correct language tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "custom" input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: This problem does **not** involve integers. It's about **text manipulation**.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an issue with large numbers.

Integer types are limited in range. To avoid such issues, treat the input as a string and then just sort the characters in the string.

For error handling, you may want to check that the input only consists of digits.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string), [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater), etc.

```
// Input
std::string s = "123456";

// Sort descending
std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<char>());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think below code will work for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool Isnum(char ch)
{
    if(ch >= 48 && ch <= 57)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool compare(char a,char b)
{
    return a>b;
}
int main()
{
    string num;
    cin >> num;
    cout << num << endl;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<num.length();i++)
    {
        if(!Isnum(num[i]))
        {
            cout << "Enter a valid number";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    sort(num.begin(),num.end(),compare);

    cout << num;


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't encourage people to ask _write the code for me_ kind of questions, by writing the code for them.

Comment: i don't seem any wrong in sharing code for new programmer.

Comment: Then you should take the [tour], read through [help], and [answer], if haven't done so. Answering such (code request) questions only encourages them to ask more of them (_why was this question answered, if it is off-topic?!_). I see no value in providing a code for someone anyway - if they are just learning, they will learn **nothing** if they didn't try to write the code themselves, and just got the code.

Comment: ok ... next onward i will create a chat room.

Comment: There's no good reason to hard-code ASCII values. Use character constants, both because they're easier to read and because they're more portable.